# How to incrementally slice through an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I have an array of strings

```
const animals = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'elephant'];
```

For the first slice I'd like to output 'ant"

```
console.log(animals.slice(0, 1));
```

For the second slice I'd like to output 'bison'

```
console.log(animals.slice(1, 2));
```

For the third slice I'd like to output 'camel'

```
console.log(animals.slice(2, 3));
```

I would like to continue slicing this way up to the length of the array to output the last string 'elephant'.

Is there a way to automate this process with variables in the `slice()` method for a given array of strings?

Comment: You need to use a (simple) function to do that for you. Also note that `slice` will return an array, so you'll actually log an array with a single animal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### With [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) iterator

```js
const animals = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'elephant']

for( let i of animals )
  console.log(  i  )
```

### with Array [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const animals = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'elephant']
animals.forEach(animal => console.log(animal))
```

Is there a reason you are insisting on using `slice` in your question's description?

Comment: I need to incrementally slice through an array of images and return each slice in React. I need to specifically return the numerical values (0,1) , (1,2) , (2,3) and so on but my slice now only returns the final pair of values  (2,3) in this example while I need to return each pair of values to output each individual image in my array into an image gallery. I just gave this as the answer because it technically did answer my original question which I simplified because my project is complicated using React, Gatsby, and GraphQL

Comment: @ElijahLee - You can edit your question to better represent your requirements, if my answer did not really help

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for each loop:

```
const animals = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'elephant'];

animals.forEach(animal => console.log(animal));
```